# Primefaces Two selectOneMenu, after selecting the first one, the second collapsed

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem on selectOneMenu, the use case is:
The first selectOneMenu is for selecting the brands of auto, like BMW, Benz, etc.
The second selectOneMenu is for selecing the concrete type, if the first is BMW, then concrete types are something like "320i, 520i.."

Here is my snippet of JSF:

```
<p:row>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputLabel for="search_car_brand" value="Brand: " />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{carController.carSearchDto.brand}"
            converter="brandConverter" effect="fade" id="search_car_brand"
            filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" height="200">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please Select a Brand..." itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{constants.availableBrands}"
                var="carBrand" itemLabel="#{carBrand.key}"
                itemValue="#{carBrand.value}" />
            <p:ajax update="search_car_type"
                listener="#{carController.handleSearchBrandChange}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputLabel for="search_car_type" value="Type: " />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{carController.carSearchDto.type}"
            converter="typeConverter" effect="fade" id="search_car_type"
            filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" height="200">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please Select a Type..." itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems
                value="#{carController.activatedCarTypesForSearch}"
                var="carType" itemLabel="#{carType.name}"
                itemValue="#{carType}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:message for="search_car_type" />
    </p:column>
</p:row>
```

As the PrimeFaces showcase taught, I use a f:ajax tag associated with a listener to update the contents of the second selectOneMenu when the first one is selected.

The listener:

```
public void handleSearchBrandChange() {
    // retrieve the brand selected from the dto
    if (carSearchDto.getBrand() == null) {
        activatedCarTypesForSearch = null;
        return;
    }

    LOGGER.info(String.format("[Search] Brand Changed to: %s", carSearchDto
            .getBrand().getName()));
    Brand selectedBrand = carSearchDto.getBrand();
    activatedCarTypesForSearch = constants.getAvailableCarTypes().get(
            selectedBrand.getName());
}
```

And here is the strange behavior:
[image: the second one has collapsed ?]

After I select the first selectOneMenu, the second one is collaped. Here is the HTML code for this element:
[image: html code]

It is obviously that the options are available, but the they are hidden:
I think `<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">` is quite strange, it may block the options from showing up ?

This problem has troubled me for two days. Any solutions for this kind of problem ?

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: I don't like the way you have to establish the no selection option. There's a JSF standard way to do that: `<f:selectItem itemValue="---" noSelectionOption="true" />`. Appart from that I always set a width for my menus: `style="width:200px"`, you can try with it. Which PF are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved by setting the css width property of the selectOneMenu:

```
<p:selectOneMenu style="width:125px;"...
```